# Why clicking on RecyclerView items return a wrong item id?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

Why clicking on RecyclerView items return a wrong item id? (It changed depending on scrolling the list)

I have an `Activity` with a button inside. I pop a dialog when the user clicks on the button. Inside the dialog, I have a `RecyclerView`.
My `RecyclerView` adapter use an web service to fetch the list:

```
setRecyclerViewAdapter(recycleView,1)
val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
val dialogView = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_menu, null)
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView)
val b = dialogBuilder.create()
b.show()
```

Below code is for fetching data from webservice and setting the `RecyclerView` adapter:

```
private fun setRecyclerViewAdapter(recycleList:RecyclerView,subjectId:Int){
     recycleList.layoutManager =LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)

        doAsync {
            categoryList= GetSubCategoriesWebService()
                    .SetRecyclerViewAdapter(subjectId)
            uiThread {
            }
            onComplete {
                val onClick= View.OnClickListener {
                    val returnIntent = Intent()
                    returnIntent.putExtra("result", result[0].toString())
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
                    finish()
                }
                val adapter = CategoryList_Adapter(categoryList,onClick,result)
                recycleList.adapter = adapter
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
```

In the `CategoryList_Adapter` I use the `onClick` for the `RecyclerView` `setOnClickListener` function ...

Note that the `Result` is an array that store the user click on RecyclerView items and give Id back to the activity and it's filled in the `CategoryList_Adapter`.

---

This is CategoryList_Adapter code:

```
class CategoryList_Adapter(private val dataList: ArrayList<CategoryListObject>?, 
                           private val listener: View.OnClickListener?, 
                           private val adSubjectId :IntArray?) 
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryList_Adapter.ItemRowHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): ItemRowHolder {
        val rowNumber = getItemViewType(i)
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.category_listview_row, viewGroup, false)
        return ItemRowHolder(view, rowNumber, dataList!![i].id)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(itemRowHolder: ItemRowHolder, i: Int) {
        Log.d("position  ", i.toString())
        itemRowHolder.itemTitle.text = dataList!![i].title
    }
     inner class ItemRowHolder(view: View,
                              rowNumber: Int,
                              subjectId: Int)
        : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var itemTitle: TextView

        init {
            view.setOnClickListener(listener)
            if(adSubjectId!=null)
                adSubjectId[0]=subjectId
     }
}
```

Why?

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Could you post your code inside the RecyclerView Adapter

Comment: its because of  result[0].toString() . 0 index

Comment: @josh_gom3z I added my RecyclerView adapter code (CategoryList_Adapter)

Comment: why dont you override `RecyclerView.Adapter#getItemId(int position)` ? did you read `onCreateViewHolder` documentation? and what is last `int` parameter?

Comment: @pskink No Id doesn't read, I am new to android development. Thank you, I'm studying about it right now.

Comment: @pskink Can you give me an article about this?

Comment: hmmm, about what?

Comment: what you say. override RecyclerView.Adapter#getItemId(int position) ...

Comment: it is used by [ViewHolder#getItemId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getItemId())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I got the same issue but I resolved it using interface.
First, you will create an interface on click class in your adapter class.

ex:
    public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
Context context;
OnTapClickListner tapClick;
List<ModelClass> datas;

public TestAdapter(Context context,OnTapClickListner tapClick,List<ModelClass> datas) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.mediaClick = mediaClick;
        this.datas = datas;
    }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

  ModelClass mainData = datas.get(position);

  holder.View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               tapClick.onItemClick(mainData);
           }
    }
 }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
       return datas.size();
  }

public interface OnTapClickListner {
        void onItemClick(ModelClass data);
    }
}
```

you have set interface look like this in adpter class.
then you will use adapter in your main class and onclick look like this:

```
TestAdapter.OnTapClickListner itemClick = new TestAdapter.OnTapClickListner() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(ModelClass data) {

    }
}
```

Itemclick use in your adpter like this:

```
new TestAdapter(this,itemClick,datas);
```

Comment: This is not my answer but is another way that solved my problem. Thank you